# How can I iterate through numpy matrix and fill values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data frames which one has two columns (list of graph edges) and another dataframe which is the location of these points. I want to search among the first data frame and replace the x and y coordinates of each point instead of points in two separate data frames.at first, I turned data frames to numpy array.
For example assume we have xx as our edge list and yy as coordinates as below:

```
xx= np.array([(4,2),(3,5)])
yy=np.array([(2,6,7),(5,5,6),(4,8,9),(3,2,2)])
```

so xx is our edge points and yy is coordinates of each point (for instance point 4 has x value of 8 and y value of 9)
then I tried to replace the nodes with coresponding x coordinate values:

```
zz=[]
for i in np.nditer(xx,order='F'):
    cc=np.where(yy[:,0]==i)
    zz.append(cc[0][0])
zz=np.array(zz)
q=[]
for i in range(xx.size):
    q.append(yy[zz[i],1])
xcoordinates=np.array(q).reshape(int(xx.size/2),2)
```

However the results are not correct after the reshape:

```
array([[8, 2],
       [6, 5]])
```

Please let me know how can I get this results for x:

```
[8,6]
[2,5]
```

I'm pretty new in python and can't understand complicated codes.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `np.nditer` was a good tool for iterating through an array?  We need to correct the documentation.  `np.nditer` is an advanced tool, not something a beginner should try use.

Comment: Actually, changing to C order fixed the problem. Please publish a book about the advanced tools which beginners should avoid. I'm sure you have good faith. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Requires some work with the second array, but you can create a lookup array that you can index with `xx`.

```
u = np.empty(yy[:, 0].max() + 1, dtype=yy.dtype)
u[yy[:, 0]] = yy[:, 1]

u[xx]
```

```
array([[8, 6],
       [2, 5]])
```

---

There are a couple of assumptions this answer makes that you should take into consideration.

1) `yy` must be unique, and it must have an integer `dtype`

2) `xx` must follow `yy.min() < xx < yy.max()` or else you will get an `IndexError`

3) All values of `xx` must be in `y[:, 0]` or you will get junk values back in the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define a little helper function - that matches an `xx` value with the first column of `yy`, and returns the value from the 2nd.

```
def foo(x):
    return yy[yy[:,0]==x, 1].item()
```

and test it a couple of values:

```
In [101]: foo(3)                                                                                     
Out[101]: 2
In [102]: foo(4)                                                                                     
Out[102]: 8
```

Instead of `nditer`, let's use `xx.flat` as the 1d iterator.

```
In [103]: for x in xx.flat: 
     ...:     print(foo(x)) 
     ...:                                                                                            
8
6
2
5
```

Or doing the same in a list comprehension:

```
In [104]: [foo(x) for x in xx.flat]                                                                  
Out[104]: [8, 6, 2, 5]
```

and use `reshape` to cast that back into an array of the same shape as `xx`:

```
In [105]: np.reshape([foo(x) for x in xx.flat],xx.shape)                                             
Out[105]: 
array([[8, 6],
       [2, 5]])
```

I also like `frompyfunc` as a way of applying a scalar function to elements of an array.  In tests it can be 2x faster than more direct iterations, yet is still easy to use without error:

```
In [106]: np.frompyfunc(foo,1,1)(xx)                                                                 
Out[106]: 
array([[8, 6],
       [2, 5]], dtype=object)
```

But the other answer show how do to do the same thing without a Python level iteration.

Another 'vectorized' approach:

Compare all values of `xx` with the 1st column of `yy`.  The result is a 3d boolean array:

```
In [107]: xx[...,None]==yy[:,0]                                                                      
Out[107]: 
array([[[False, False,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False, False]]])
```

`where` is a 3 element tuple.  2 elements index `xx`, the last `yy`:

```
In [108]: np.where(xx[...,None]==yy[:,0])                                                            
Out[108]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]), array([2, 0, 3, 1]))
In [109]: yy[np.where(xx[...,None]==yy[:,0])[2],1]                                                   
Out[109]: array([8, 6, 2, 5])
```